# Transparent navbar fallback

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a transparent bootstrap navbar, with the second element on my page being a hero header with a margin of -50 (so the hero image is behind the menu, which is how I want it).

However, on some pages there's no header image and I'm left with a transparent navbar which is not visible on the default white background.

How can I best write a fallback for the navbar to have some kind of background if there's no hero on the page? Preferably pure css. Maybe with some smart layering? Can't figure it out.

Comment: Please provide more code or a demo. This is not enough for us to solve your problem. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how you can provide a viable demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question does not provide the HTML that you are using, I have tried to guess the layout of your project. The easiest way to do this is to use pseudo classes of css. You can use it to show an image or some color behind your nav bar.

The reason why we give it to the container is that when the hero image is there, then the pseudo element will be behind the hero image and will not be visible. But when the hero image is missing, the pseudo element will visible.

CSS:

```
.container::before {
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Refer the working prototype below.

```css
.nav {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
  display: block;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">Nav Content</nav>
</div>
```